# R: field '$addToSet' in '$addToSet' is not valid for storage: rmongodb

Tags: r, mongodb, rmongodb

I am trying to write a generic upsert for a tick Database in R.

The python code would be:

```
collection.update({'symbol':'somesymbol', 'sha':'SoM3__W3|Re|7__Sh@'},

                   {'$set':{segment:5},

                    '$addToSet': {'parent':parent_id}}},

                     upsert=True)
```

In R I am using rmongodb and trying to build the BSON Objects

```
#get the query

mtch_b<-mongo.bson.buffer.create()

mongo.bson.buffer.append(mtch_b, "symbol", "somesymbol")

mongo.bson.buffer.append(mtch_b, "sha", "SoM3__W3|Re|7__Sh@")

mtch<-mongo.bson.from.buffer(mtch_b)



#set the segment

qry_b<-mongo.bson.buffer.create()

mongo.bson.buffer.start.object(qry_b, "$set")

    mongo.bson.buffer.append(qry_b, "segment", 5)

            mongo.bson.buffer.start.object(qry_b, "$addToSet")

                mongo.bson.buffer.append(qry_b, "parent", "Initial")

            mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(qry_b) #end of $addtoSet object

mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(qry_b) #end of $set object

qry_bsn <-mongo.bson.from.buffer(qry_b)



mongo.update(mongo, "M__test.tmp", mtch, qry_bsn, flags=mongo.update.upsert)
```

When I run this I get an error:

```
"The dollar ($) prefixed field '$addToSet' in '$addToSet' is not valid for storage."
```

looking at the qry_bsn:

```
qry_bsn

    $set : 3        

            segment : 4     

                    0 : 1    1.000000

                    1 : 1    2.000000

                    2 : 1    3.000000

                    3 : 1    4.000000



            $addToSet : 3   

                    parent : 2       Initial
```

When I remove the $addToSet, append and finish objects of the $addToSet object the query runs fine.

Any help on how to do this would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you see the query, the `$addToSet` is displayed at the level of segment, which is incorrect. It should be displayed at the level of `$set`. This indicates that your `bson buffer` creation is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find reason for not using `mongo.bson.from.list`. It make all `mongo.bson.buffer.*` calls for you. And it is much less chance to produce a bug with bson construction.

```
query <- mongo.bson.from.list(list("symbol" = "somesymbol", "sha" = "SoM3__W3|Re|7__Sh@"))
upd_obj <- mongo.bson.from.list(list('$set' = list('segment' = 1:4), '$addToSet' = list('parent' = 'PARENT_ID')))
mongo.update(mongo = mongo, ns = "M__test.tmp", criteria = query, objNew = upd_obj, flags=mongo.update.upsert)
```